# WordPress plugin for WooCommerce product export/import

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a WordPress plugin to export/import WooCommerce product data from one site to another. There seems to be so many different plugins available. Any one can share your experience?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: WebToffee [WooCommerce import-export](https://profiles.wordpress.org/webtoffee/#content-plugins) plugins are a sure bet

Answer (score 1):

Try using this [product import export](https://www.webtoffee.com/product/product-import-export-woocommerce/) plugin. It is highly likely that you will face issues if you have a huge amount of products that you want import or export. The support provided is great and will help you navigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used `csv` to import 2500 products. Plugin is available for import is

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/product-csv-import-suite-importing-products/

which is easy to use and can handle custom field and variable product also.Other one is also available if you have only simple product the you can use `Ultimate WooCommerce CSV Importer`

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-woocommerce-csv-loader/

Answer (score 0):

For all my clients sites, i use wp all import and wp all export. It's not free, but the best solution i've found so far.